# GPflow - Updating Model with new Data

Tags: gpflow

I have trained a model in GPflow and ultimately I would like to take this posterior distribution and use it as the prior in a new instance.  I reviewed the docs and couldn't see anything.  I did see the [following link](https://gpflow.readthedocs.io/en/master/notebooks/tailor/updating_models_with_new_data.html) which sounded very good, but it appears to be a placeholder and is empty.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between "using the posterior as a new prior" and "adding more data to the model". The former is a bit more of a research question, see for example https://github.com/thangbui/streaming_sparse_gp (GPflow 1.0) and https://github.com/pmorenoz/RecyclableGP (PyTorch+GPy). The latter is easy to do (for GPflow's VGP model, see the implementation in the [Trieste Bayesian Optimization library](https://github.com/secondmind-labs/trieste/blob/9847d3f4847e732e30a5b80be25d181c4ee2aebc/trieste/models/model_interfaces.py#L272) built on top of GPflow).